# How to keep up with PHP Frameworks evolution?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, cloud

So I'm about to start a big Property Management System for the cloud. This Hotel system already exists in VB.net technologies, and now we are porting the whole system to web.

We are trying to decide between ASP.net or PHP, we are thinking on PHP because ASP.net would cost too much on licensing and servers. So there is Laravel, Symphony, CodeIgniter, Zend, etc..

The thing is, this project is suppose to live for years to come. But we feel like getting constraint ed by using a PHP framework, because every time the framework gets updated then we need to update our whole system. For example.. now Laravel got updated from version 4 to 5. And the whole folder structure changed. I can't imagine having our big system needing to be updated and keep up to every Laravel version update. How do you keep up with this ?

Also, what would happened if Laravel disappears, its the trendy fashion now. But we see PHP frameworks come and go.

Would it be wiser not to use any php framework and building everything from scratch to have more control over it ?

Comment: Totally depends on you're developers. Personally, if I had the choice I'd avoid PHP frameworks so that I have 100% control over everything, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: If you're used to working with .net, then you're used to working with a framework already, so I'd not dismiss working with a framework in PHP; it saves you a lot of effort in comparison with writing your own, and re-inventing the wheel yet again

Comment: But while some PHP frameworks come and go, others such as ZF and Symfony are well established and with active thriving communities, and aren't likely to disappear on a whim; and while a major upgrade to a framework may break backward compatibility, this isn't common, and you're not forced to upgrade with every major change either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first note that using a framework is primarily meant to solve two issues;

1. Force coding into a certain 'format'. Collaboratively working on code can generate 'hacked' solutions, or unmaintainable code. A framework can be the force which helps keep these things in check.
2. A framework comes with a certain core-code which handles for example database abstraction, routing, etc. which can save you a lot of time to develop yourself.

An extra thing to mention; when implementing new features, there is the possibility someone has built it before and maybe even better than you would have anticipated.

Keeping up with the framework should not be too hard, as long as you abide by the coding guidelines of the framework. With the bigger frameworks, new releases have (or after sometime generate) tutorials on how to port your previous version into the new version format.

Choosing which framework to use, is a question which is opinion-based and not suited to discuss here, but keep in mind that you choose your framework according to your needs. Also check how big the community is and how much 3rd party plugins/code exists (the more, the longer the framework will last).

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You could see a framework as a base to start from. Remember that you get all the code! Look at the code. Do you like it? Does it fit your requirements? Using a framework gives you a huge advantage over making everything yourself from scratch.

But do you need to update? Would you update your own code constantly? Perhaps it's not always needed. Sure, if there is a security issue you should do something about it, but seeing every update to a framework as essential is just plain nonsense.

I build projects aimed at specific versions of frameworks and libraries. I try to build in flexibility so I can swap out frameworks and libraries, and versions, but I often find that I stick with what's working.

Some people might not like this, and argue you should always be on the latest version, but I find that completely impractical.

Comment: The biggest argument to update your framework code is that you can keep up with the latest developments in the field, and the maintenance is easier. If you have to maintain a project which uses a framework used a decade ago... You are gonna have a bad time...

Comment: What @RichardBernards says is what I mean. We cannot stuck our product in a decade old framework version. As with PHP (the language) we would also need to be updating it, and check compatibility constantly. Because then, the day we decide to upgrade, it will need a long set of changes in our main product.

People seem to use these frameworks, for small to medium projects that might die in a year or two. But the product we are trying to build is going to be the main company product for the years to come, so the whole dev team will marry the framework.

Comment: You clearly seem to know what you need to do. Any software you use, I mean really any software, will be outdated after a decade. So if you know that you will want to keep your software up-to-date that long you will have to commit the resources to do so. Nobody can predict the future of a framework over such a long time, so you do take a gamble. Whatever you choose, it might turn out to be right or wrong choice.